# Printing simple and duplex in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a C# 2010 application that uses Crystal Reports for VS2010.

My client has a pretty awkward request. He wants to print an invoice for a client. He wants the whole invoice to be printed on only one side of a page, but he wants the payment information to appear on the backside of the last page.

So basically, he wants the whole report to be printed single-sided, except for the last page, which he wants printed double-sided (duplex).

**Is there a way to do this using CR and C#?** I know he could turn the page and print the payment options manually, but that's not really helpful. I need to be able to do it in the same report.

Comment: You may be able to accomplish this with some hackery.  I would try starting with creating a dummy section and making the section start on a new page or set new page after if it is not on the last record.  The payment information could be put in the report summary and you could also start on a new page. So it would be page, blank page, page, blank page, page, summary.

Comment: Of course you would also have to make sure that report was printed with the option to print on both sides.

Comment: That would actually work! I am guessing I'll have to write some code for that but I have no experience writing Crystal Reports code ... Can you please write the required code (I'm guessing it will be an if - else statement) in an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

> You may be able to accomplish this with some hackery. I would try starting with creating a dummy section and making the section start on a new page or set new page after if it is not on the last record. The payment information could be put in the report summary and you could also start on a new page. So it would be page, blank page, page, blank page, page, summary.

The dummy section would have its 'New Page Before' and 'New Page After' set to `Not OnLastRecord`.
The report summary section should have 'New Page Before' set to `True`.

Comment: I don't have Summary section, I only have Report Header, Page Header, Details, Page Footer, Report Footer. I assumed you mean the details section, but doing what you said does not work. It inserts a page break after each record, rather than a new page. Also, the details section has a "New page after x records" option, which works fine with what I need, but "New page before" has no x records option, so that messes it up. Any other ideas?